# Missing 1 required positional argument - Python

Tags: python, api, gitlab

I use gitlab-python module for get all commits from all branches in list of repository

When I try to get list of branches from projects I receive error

`TypeError: get_branches() missing 1 required positional argument: 'project'`

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url="https://gitlab.site.com", private_token="token")

projects_list = ['23', '218', '239', '246', '245', '265']

def get_projects():
    for project_id in projects_list:
        project = gl.projects.get(project_id)
        return (project)
        
def get_branches(project):
    branches = project.branches.list(get_all=True, all=True)
    for branch in branches:
        print(branch)

def main():
    get_projects()
    get_branches()

main()
```

How can I provide arguments for changes to fix it?

Comment: `get_branches()` requires a `project` argument.

Comment: `get_projects()` returns a `project`. According to the definition, `def get_branches(project):` accepts a `project` as its first argument. The solution boils down to passing the `project` from `get_projects()` to `get_branches`.

Comment: `get_projects()` just returns the first project, since `return` ends the loop. You probably want to return a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

As it is obvious in the definition of the function *get_branches(project)*; you need to pass it a project as an argument.
You may write a **loop** which iterates over all projects returned by *get_projects()* and for each project you can use *get_branches(project)* (given the project as an argument).

```
for project in get_projects():
    get_branches(project)
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_projects()` should return a list of projects, not just the first project in the loop.

You need to pass a project to `get_branches()`. You can do this by looping over the results of `get_projects()`.

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url="https://gitlab.site.com", private_token="token")

projects_list = ['23', '218', '239', '246', '245', '265']

def get_projects():
    return [gl.projects.get(project_id) for project_id in projects_list]
        
def get_branches(project):
    branches = project.branches.list(get_all=True, all=True)
    for branch in branches:
        print(branch)

def main():
    for project in get_projects():
        get_branches(project)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar! Does it possible to split each branches list to repository?
Like as, 
develop -
feature/dev/branch1;
production -
feature/prod/branch1,
feature/prod/branch2

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the gitlab API, but I expect it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version of your code

```
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url="https://gitlab.site.com", private_token="token")

projects_list = ['23', '218', '239', '246', '245', '265']


def main():
    projects = [gl.projects.get(project_id) for project_id in projects_list]
    branches = {str(p): p.branches.list(get_all=True, all=True) for p in projects}


main()
```